# PowerShell@2 module failure does not stop pipeline run

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I have the following module in my Azure Pipelines script.

```
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: "Delete TEST DB"
      condition: eq('${{ parameters.dataresetenv }}', 'test')
      env:
        TEST_DB_USERNAME: $(TEST_DB_USERNAME)
        TEST_DB_PASSWORD: $(TEST_DB_PASSWORD)
      inputs:
        failOnStderr: true
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $resourceGroupName = 'MY-TEST-RESOURCE-GROUP'
          $ServerName = "my-test-server.database.windows.net"
          sqlcmd -S $ServerName -U "$(TEST_DB_USERNAME)" -P "$(TEST_DB_PASSWORD)"  -q "DROP Database [MY-TEST-DB];"
```

Right now, sqlcmd fails and exits on error code '1' but the pipeline does not stop upon failure (see screenshot below). The "Backup Prod DB and Deploy" step had to manually cancelled.

How do I get the pipeline to stop running upon failure of this step? It is my understanding that 'continueOnError' should default to 'false' and I have not changed that. I added `condition: not(or(failed(), canceled()))` to the following step but that did not work.

[image]

Comment: The `errorActionPreference` preference variable can sometimes be made fun of.
I would try setting it to `stop`, just in case.
Also, I would have a look at the `failOnStderr` advanced setting. | Help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/powershell-v2?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: Hi, if the issue is still unsolved, can you share your full yaml for more investigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about the PowerShell task.

According to your screenshot, the "Backup Prod DB and Deploy" is not a step/task, but a job name.

In the document [Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions)  and [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#conditions) of jobs ,

> By default Azure DevOps YAML pipeline jobs run in parallel unless the `dependsOn` value is set.

> By default, a job runs if it doesn't depend on any other job, or if all of the jobs that it depends on have completed and succeeded.

So if you want the "Backup Prod DB and Deploy" job runs depends on the former job's success, you can add the `dependsOn` and `conditions` keyword to the job.

Sample yaml:

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: This is first job
    steps:
      - script: exit 1
  - job: A2
    displayName: Backup Prod DB and Deploy
    dependsOn: A1
    condition: succeeded('A1')
    steps:
      - script: hello A2
- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: "hello B1"
  - job: B2
    steps:
      - script: "hello B2"
```

Result:

The job "Backup Prod DB and Deploy" will not run when the first job failed.
[image: result]